# windows phone 7 application c#-accessing video library

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I just want to bind a listbox to a video list ,the videos are in video library in windows
phone.I have already searched a lot and spent lot of time.But no articles are there to access
video library in windows phone 7.

Any help will help me a lot,Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not access to videos from media library in windows phone. You can use MediaLibrary that will give you access to metadata related to existing songs and pictures, but that's all. Sad but true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading your project to Windows Phone 8.1 which has access to video library.

Check this out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx